# Why do we need to use OPENQUERY to pull data from Sybase to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sybase, linked-server, openquery

I have data on a Sybase server and want to get the data to my SQL Server instance. I have a linked server defined to the Sybase query and when I try to use the 4 part naming convention to access the data, I get the following error:

> Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "[Sybase Instance]" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "COL1" (compile-time ordinal 10) of object "[Table on Sybase Instance]" was reported to have a "DBTYPE" of 131 at compile time and 6 at run time.

However, when I use `OPENQUERY` this error does not occur and I get the correct results. Anybody have any insight as to how and why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

openquery does not care about nullable columns, the error is basically a difference in compile time vs real time query plan for the linked server